# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied after deploying Angular in IIS Development Server

Tags: angular, iis, web-deployment

Can you help me figure out what I missed on deploying my Angular 8 app in the dev server.

First, I build my app using this command.

```
ng build --configuration=dev --base-href /my-sample-app/
```

Second, in the server I paste the content of `dist` folder in

```
D:\webapps\mysampleapp
```

Third, I add new Application in the IIS. I set the `alias` to `my-sample-app` and point the `physical path` to `D:\webapps\mysampleapp`

The content of my web.config is below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `base href` in my `Index.html` is this

```html
<base href="/my-sample-app/">
```

My issue was, everytime I hit `https://dev.company.com/my-sample-web` I get an `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.` error.

[image]

But, when I try to access other page like `https://dev.company.com/my-sample-web/other-component` it will load the page as expected.

I also have this route in my angular routing.

```js
{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  loadChildren: './feature/my-sample-app/sampleapp.module#SampleAppModule',
  canActivate: [Auth_Guard]
}
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

TIA!

Comment: try https://dev.company.com/my-sample-web/my-sample-web

Comment: @ShlokNangia yeah, this works. But, what i want is `dev.company.com/my-sample-web` should load the component already.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding `href="/my-sample-app/` in index.html manually then remove it from `ng build` command

Comment: No I'm not modifying index.html manually. Since I can set it in `ng build --base-href`

Comment: try to replace routing part with {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },

Comment: and also try removing my-sample-app from ng build command, because I have deployed angular app many time and never use this but yes I update the path in index.html and web.config... please try this first

Comment: I don't get it why you need to remove the `--base-href` in `ng build` and update the index.html manually. since the idea was the same. but will give it a try

Comment: also in web.config

Comment: What would be the value of web.config?

Comment: change the url here <action type="Rewrite" url="/my-sample-app/" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211612/discussion-between-klaydze-and-shlok-nangia).

Comment: was there any solution for that?